# Separating /boot from the rest of the System

Tags: linux, raid, boot, mdadm

I have a theoretical system configuration question; If I build my system on a software RAID1 but put /boot on a USB.. could there be problems if the RAID becomes dirty?  The setup would be as follows:

```
USB ----------->  /boot

RAID1
 sda
 sdb --> md0 -->  /
 sdc
```

My question is; if any of the drives fail, would I still be able to boot if the RAID is in a dirty status?

Comment: You can also install the system on USB and use the raid as data partition

Answer (score 0):

No problem at all, that I know of... but you can try by yourself disconnecting one drive (and then re-sync-ing it again later...) and see if it boots...(it should...)

Comment: Only if it's not raid0

Comment: he said it's RAID1...